# NumberFormatExceptions being thrown everywhere. Why? (parseInt)

Tags: java, exception, parseint, numberformatexception, text-based

First time poster here with a seriously annoying issue. I have decided to create a text-based RPG in Java in order to consolidate what I have been learning. And with all lengthy games, a saving/loading system is necessary. This is where my problems arise.

I have created a menu system, which works fine. However, when I decide to start a new game, I get NumberFormatExceptions thrown left, right and center. My source code is down below, ANY help at all would be very much appreciated. I have separated each important section into separate Java files.

```
//Imports
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

//'Choices' - By Yemi Oladimeji/YemZeee

class Choices{
        public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String startChoice = null;

    //Introduction begin
        GameMethods.space();
        System.out.println("########  ##    ## ######## ######## ########            ######## ########");
        System.out.println("##        ##    ## ##    ##    ##    ##       ##       ##        ");
        System.out.println("##        ##    ## ##    ##    ##    ##       ##       ##        ");
        System.out.println("##        ######## ##    ##    ##    ##       ######    ###### ");
        System.out.println("##        ##    ## ##    ##    ##    ##       ##             ##");
        System.out.println("##        ##    ## ##    ##    ##    ##       ##             ##");
        System.out.println("########  ##    ## ######## ######## ######## ######## ########");
        GameMethods.space();
        System.out.println("Greetings, and welcome to Choices, a 2D text-based RPG!");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("<P>lay :: <A>bout :: <Q>uit");
        startChoice = input.nextLine();
        GameMethods.sChoice(startChoice);
        }
}//End Choices.java
```

This is the beginning of the GameMethods.java file

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GameMethods extends ChoiceSaveMethods{

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String startChoice;
static String loadChoice;

public static void buffer(){
    try{
        System.in.read();
        } catch(Exception e){
    }
}

public static void space(){
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public static void quit(){
System.exit(1);
}

public static void menuCall(){
    System.out.println("<P>lay :: <A>bout :: <Q>uit");
    startChoice = input.nextLine();
    GameMethods.sChoice(startChoice);
}

public static void sChoice(String startChoice){
    if(startChoice.equals("A")){
        GameMethods.space();
        System.out.println("This is a text-based RPG, created by Yemi Oladimeji.");
        System.out.println("It focuses on the story and said story changes depend on \nthe choices you make in this world.");
        System.out.println("As it is quite story driven, there will be the option at \nthe end of your journey to output your story to a text file for you to save and keep.");
        System.out.println("Now that you know what the game is about, do you want to go back to the menu? \n(Y/N)");
        String aChoice = input.nextLine();
        if(aChoice.equals("Y")){
            GameMethods.menuCall();
        } else if(aChoice.equals("N")){
            System.out.println("Or would you like to quit the game?");
            String qChoice = input.nextLine();
            if(qChoice.equals("Y")){
                System.exit(1);
            } else if(qChoice.equals("N")){
                GameMethods.menuCall();
            }
        }   
    }
    if(startChoice.equals("Q")){
        GameMethods.quit();
    }
    if(startChoice.equals("P")){
        try{
            BufferedReader saveFile = new BufferedReader(new    FileReader("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheGame\\SaveFiles\\TextSave1.txt"));
            areaMarkers[0] = Integer.parseInt(saveFile.readLine());
            areaMarkers[1] = Integer.parseInt(saveFile.readLine());
            areaMarkers[2] = Integer.parseInt(saveFile.readLine());
            areaMarkers[3] = Integer.parseInt(saveFile.readLine());
            saveFile.close();

                for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                if(areaMarkers[x] == 1){
                    System.out.println("A save game has been located. Would you like to load it?(Y/N)");
                    loadChoice = input.nextLine();
                    if(loadChoice.equals("Y")){
                        System.out.println("The save/load feature works.");
                    } else if(loadChoice.equals("N")){
                        System.out.println("Starting new game...");
                        GameMethods.gameStart();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        forestArea();
    }
}

public static void gameStart(){
    //Introduction begin
        GameMethods.space();
        System.out.println("Welcome to 'Choices'. You influence this world with your decisions. You react \nhow you wish...");
        GameMethods.space();
        System.out.println("This game was built to immerse you in a hooking storyline with no graphics, \nand only your imagination can help with that. \nThat and some audio. For that purpose, I recommend that you use headphones \nwhilst playing this game.");
        System.out.println("I require two pieces of information. Your name. What is it?\n(This is what you will be called in game)");
        System.out.println("Your name: ");
        String name1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("And the name for this user account\n(So the program can locate the required files): ");
        String userName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("There are two rules...");
        System.out.println("This (*) means a flashback is occurring.");
        System.out.println("And when there is a pause, it means that you \nshould press Enter/Return to continue.");
        System.out.println("You get that? Good.");
        System.out.println("Now. Let us begin your game and remember. \nYour     choices affect your path.");
    //Introduction end
}
}
```

And this is the last Java file, the one which contains the areas and the saving method:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ChoiceSaveMethods{

//Area variables:
static int[] areaMarkers = new int[4];
static int[] areaChoices = new int[4];
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void forestArea(){
    GameMethods.space();
    System.out.println("Area 1: Forest. What would you like to do here?: ");
    System.out.println("1 - Save the game?");
    System.out.println("2 - View a description of the area?");
    System.out.println("3 - Progress to the next area?");
    System.out.println("4 - Exit to the main menu?");

   areaChoices[0] = input.nextInt();

   if(areaChoices[0] == 1){
        try{
            FileWriter saveFile1 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheGame\\SaveFiles\\TextSave1.txt");
            areaMarkers[0] = 1;
            saveFile1.write(1);
            System.out.println("Game has been saved successfully.");
            saveFile1.close();
            forestArea();
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } else if(areaChoices[0] == 2){
        System.out.println("This is a forest. It has trees.");
        forestArea();
    } else if(areaChoices[0] == 3){
        System.out.println("Progressing to next area...");
        cityArea();
    } else if(areaChoices[0] == 4){
        System.out.println("Returning to main menu.");
        GameMethods.menuCall();
    }
}

public static void cityArea(){
    GameMethods.space();
    System.out.println("Area 2: City. What would you like to do here?: ");
    System.out.println("1 - Save the game?");
    System.out.println("2 - View a description of the area?");
    System.out.println("3 - Progress to the next area?");
    System.out.println("4 - Exit to the main menu?");

    areaChoices[1] = input.nextInt();

    if(areaChoices[1] == 1){
        try{
            FileWriter saveFile2 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheGame\\SaveFiles\\TextSave1.txt");
            areaMarkers[1] = 1;
            saveFile2.write(areaMarkers[1]);
            System.out.println("Game has been saved successfully.");
            saveFile2.close();
            cityArea();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        } else if(areaChoices[1] == 2){
            System.out.println("This is a city. There are alot of people.");
            cityArea();
        } else if(areaChoices[1] == 3){
            System.out.println("Progressing to next area...");
            magmaArea();
        } else if(areaChoices[1] == 4){
            System.out.println("Returning to main menu.");
            GameMethods.menuCall();
        }
}

public static void magmaArea(){
    GameMethods.space();
    System.out.println("Area 3: Magma Pool. What would you like to do here?: ");
    System.out.println("1 - Save the game?");
    System.out.println("2 - View a description of the area?");
    System.out.println("3 - Progress to the next area?");
    System.out.println("4 - Exit to the main menu?");

    areaChoices[2] = input.nextInt();

    if(areaChoices[2] == 1){
        try{
            FileWriter saveFile3 = new    FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheGame\\SaveFiles\\TextSave1.txt");
            areaMarkers[2] = 1;
            saveFile3.write(areaMarkers[2]);
            System.out.println("Game has been saved successfully.");
            saveFile3.close();
            magmaArea();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if(areaChoices[2] == 2){
        System.out.println("A blazing pool of molten rock. Very hot.");
        magmaArea();
    } else if(areaChoices[2] == 3){
        System.out.println("Progressing to next area.");
        hospitalArea();
    } else if(areaChoices[2] == 4){
        System.out.println("Returning to main menu.");
        GameMethods.menuCall();
    }
}

public static void hospitalArea(){
    GameMethods.space();
    System.out.println("Area 4: Hospital. What would you like to do here?: ");
    System.out.println("1 - Save the game?");
    System.out.println("2 - View a description of the area?");
    System.out.println("3 - Exit to the main menu.");

    areaChoices[3] = input.nextInt();

    if(areaChoices[3] == 1){
        try
            {
            FileWriter saveFile4 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Yemi\\Desktop\\TheGame\\SaveFiles\\TextSave1.txt");
            areaMarkers[3] = 1;
            saveFile4.write(areaMarkers[3]);
            System.out.println("Game has been successfully saved.");
            saveFile4.close();
            hospitalArea();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if(areaChoices[3] == 2){
        System.out.println("A disused, abandoned hospital. It has an eerie feel     about it.");
        hospitalArea();
    } else if(areaChoices[3] == 3){
        System.out.println("Returning to the main menu...");
        GameMethods.menuCall();
    }
}
}
```

And the exception which is being thrown is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at GameMethods.sChoice(GameMethods.java:59)
    at Choices.main(Choices.java:32)
```

I realize this is a lot to be asking for, especially for a first time poster, but I am seriously running out of ideas here. Feel free to copy and run the code. Any answers at all would be very much appreciated. Again, thank you.

Comment: I only read one line (the first line of the stack trace) but it's telling you that you can't parse an empty string as a number.  It's fairly obvious that either your file contains blank lines or there is a problem finding and/or reading from the file.  You should use basic debugging steps (like using a debugger) to troubleshoot this.

Comment: It looks like the file that you are reading is empty...it has initial line or any of the rest of 4 lines is blank..

Comment: Here's some good advice that it took me too long to follow: _Write your program in small steps._  If one part of the program has to read from a file, create a very simple test program that can read a file.  When you get that to work, incorporate that into your project and move to the next small step.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [jahroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778118/jahroy); the stack trace is telling you what's wrong.  Looking at the code you're trying to read four integers on four lines from your save file, but your save logic in the *Area() methods only ever write one integer.  Maybe you intended to write out an integer and three zeros instead?

Probably better to use a single integer to indicate the location in your save file (0=forest, 1=city, 2=magma, etc.) rather than four 0/1 ints on separate lines.